# Why does my PHP email come without HTML and utf-8?

Tags: php, html, smtp

I have a contact form and want to format the output email in HTML and use charset utf-8 as I need some special character. I have following code, but it's not working.
Edit: The email is sent, but without html and utf-8.

```
<?php 
if ($_POST["email"]<>'') { 
    $ToEmail = 'contact@domain.com'; 
    $EmailSubject = 'Email Subject'; 
    $mailheader = 'From: donotreply@domain.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To:' .$_POST["email"]. "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
        'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n".
        'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'."\r\n".
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "<b>Navn:</b> ".$_POST["name"]."\r\n"; 
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "<b>Telefon:</b> ".$_POST["telephone"]."\r\n";
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "<b>Email:</b> ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n\r\n"; 
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "".nl2br($_POST["message"])."\r\n"; 
    mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure"); 
?>
```

Comment: Not working? You expect us to guess __how__ it is not working?

Comment: Well, that code _states_ that the content is of type HTML, but most likely `$_POST["message"]` does not contain such markup, but plain text. There are no magic pixies that will convert and enhance your text just because you say it is HTML markup. You need to create valid markup, so also document tags around the content. Otherwise you risk that intermediate email servers "fix" your message.

Comment: its also open to header injection.

Comment: The code use to work with html and utf8 but I had to change the mail header to get a fixed "from" and "reply to" from contact form. So the only change I made was to the mail header. @arkascha

Answer (score 0):

Try changing header from

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n"; 
to 
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
```

Its better use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) This will allow you to send mails via a SMTP server

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but not sure how changing charset to iso-8859-1 is going to help me as I need to use utf-8 due to some Scandinavian letters.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the only thing that was wrong was the order of the code. By moving `'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();` below Content-Type the mail is encoded correct.

This is how I fixed it:

`$mailheader = 'From: donotreply@domain.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To:' .$_POST["email"]. "\r\n" .
        'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n".
        'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'."\r\n".
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();`

Comment: Try below encoding before sending mail.

utf8_encode($MESSAGE_BODY);